# Trouble setting up a laravel instance across servers using git

Tags: laravel, git, bitbucket

I am struggling with properly configuring a git workflow for a laravel project. I created the laravel project locally. At the base directory I used the git init command. Then connected the repository to the bitbucket repository set up by the company I am working for like so:

```
git remote add origin https://address/xyz.git
```

I then made some new changes to a few of the files. Did a commit and then pushed to origin like this:

```
git push -u origin master
```

Now I logged into our development box (which is not my local dev box). Built the laravel default laravel application and then tried to pull down the project specific files by connected the dev box's laravel directory to the same repository, but I keep getting the following error:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    .gitignore
    composer.json
    package.json
    resources/js/app.js
    resources/js/bootstrap.js
    webpack.mix.js
```

Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.

I know I probably missed some simple step or did not set up the development box correctly, but I can't find this scenario in the documentation and I can't seem to discover what I did wrong. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the repository on the main development box has some local changes that are not checked into git. Run the command

```
git status
```

On the remote development box. This will tell you any local changes.

If you want to remove any local unchecked in changes you can type

```
git reset --hard (resets any tracked files)
git clean -Xdf (resets all untracked files)
```

If you want to preserve any local changes, you can type

```
git stash
git stash --pop (recovers the changes - this may induce some conflicts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for listing those tools Ben W, but it turns out that I the wording of my question was deceptive. When I went to the second machine (the development box), I should have built the laravel instance by using the git clone command.

```
git clone https://address/xyz.git
```

What I did instead, was build another full instance of laravel and try to link it to the same repository I created from the first box (my local notebook).

I upvoted your answer anyhow Brad W. because those are all great tools to know. Thanks.